# Django uwsgi deploy. Unable to find 'application'

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

Has a problem when starting uwsgi:

```
unable to find "application" callable in file dashboard/wsgi.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/dashboard.sock
chdir = /srv/http/depo-dashboard/
wsgi-file = dashboard/wsgi.py
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
chmod-socket = 666
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dashboard.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

It seems to me that everthing should be ok, but it isn't..

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think I've found solution: just replace this `wsgi-file = dashboard/wsgi.py` to this `module = dashboard.wsgi:application`